# Difference between epoch time and normal date in seconds - python

Tags: python

I have two variables : One is epoch time and other is normal datetime,

```
df['epochtime']

0       1457586382
1       1457586382
2       1457586391
3       1457586692
4       1457586391
5       1457586391
6       1457586692
7       1457586692
8       1457572611

df['time']
0      2016-03-10 00:06:21.903
1      2016-03-10 00:06:21.908
2      2016-03-10 00:06:30.895
3      2016-03-10 00:06:30.895
4      2016-03-10 00:06:30.899
5      2016-03-10 00:06:30.899
6      2016-03-10 00:06:31.045
7      2016-03-10 00:06:31.094
8      2016-03-10 01:16:51.390
```

I want the difference between these two times in seconds. The following is my trying,

```
pd.to_datetime(df['epochtime'], unit ='s' ) - df['time']
```

The following is my output,

```
0               00:00:00.097000
1               00:00:00.092000
2               00:00:00.105000
3               00:05:01.105000
4               00:00:00.101000
5               00:00:00.101000
6               00:05:00.955000
7               00:05:00.906000
8      -1 days +23:59:59.610000
```

I want to make this as integer in seconds. Also for the 8th value for some strange reason getting difference as -1 days, where it should be seconds only. Can anybody help me getting the seconds difference as integer ?

Comment: I suggest you should first understand the definition of 'epoch time'. From there your solution flows naturally.

Comment: check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python

Comment: @ChrisC73 I agree that I am new to epoch time. But I have read about that and felt that i know a little about it. I didn't get why you are saying that.

Comment: @haifzhan how does that answer my question?

Comment: @Observer: Or not so naturally, perhaps. Epoch is in seconds => convert datetime to epoch and do your arithmetic.

Comment: @Observer  because you cannot use epoch time minus datetime. You haveto convert datetime to epoch and then do the math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert datetime to epoch time, and then do the arithmetic subtraction.

As you said you are always use UTC time, you need to use `calendar.timegm()`  because it takes UTC time as parameter.

```
import time
import datetime
import calendar

TIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

def local_datetime_2_timestamp(local_datetime):
    '''strptime takes local datetime as parameter'''
    timestamp = str(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.
        strptime(local_datetime, TIME_FORMAT).timetuple()))[:-2]
    return timestamp

def utc_2_timestamp(utc_datetime):
    '''timegm takes UTC time as parameter'''
    return calendar.timegm(utc_datetime.timetuple())

print local_datetime_2_timestamp("2016-03-10 00:06:21.903".split(".")[0])
print utc_2_timestamp(datetime.datetime(2016,3,10,0,6,21))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import mktime, strptime

date_a = '20-01-2015 11:05:02'
epoch_b = 1457586692

epoch_a = int(mktime(strptime(date_a, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')))

print(epoch_a - epoch_b)
```

Comment: `This is the inverse function of localtime(). Its argument is the struct_time or full 9-tuple (since the dst flag is needed; use -1 as the dst flag if it is unknown) which expresses the time in local time, not UTC.` quoted from python documents

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.